# Setting value={file} in <option> tag and accessing from an onChange function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, html-select

I am using React. I am trying to get a featured image from a list of files that the user has selected. I am trying to make the user select a number which corresponds to an image file. I have the following:

```
    const handleFeatureImageChange = (event) => {
        setFeatureImage(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
      };
    
    return(
    {selectedFiles.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                  <select name="is_feature" onChange={handleFeatureImageChange}>
                    {selectedFiles.map((selectedFile, index) => {
                      return (
                        <option key={index} value={selectedFile}>
                          {index + 1}{console.log(selectedFile)}
                        </option>
                      );
                    })}
                  </select>
                </div>
              )}
    );
```

But `console.log(event.target.value)` inside the `handleFeatureImageChange` function prints `[object File]` as a string. But I want the actual file object there. `console.log(selectedFile)` inside the `jsx` prints the actual file object. How can I get the file object in the `handleFeatureImageChange` function ?

Comment: How about you set the value of option tags as index rather than selectedFile and get the file from selectedFiles array as selectedFiles[Number(event.target.value)] in the function handleFeatureImageChange. I think that its better to not set object for option tag value attribute and hence the index so that you can get the specific object from the array

Comment: can you create a demo for this it's very helpful for me